# getting weird warnings while sending data to firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using flutter and while sending data to firebase firestore. I received some warnings/errors in terminal

basically im building a ecommerce app and sending user credentials to firestore, though my app is working fine just got these warnings while sending data i just want to know what are these warnings and meaning of this

THANK YOU

```
Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
 Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
 Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
```

**my code**

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:fur/Providers/orders.dart';
import 'package:fur/Screens/OrderSumm.dart';
import 'package:fur/items/OrderItem.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Address extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _AddressState createState() => _AddressState();
}

class _AddressState extends State<Address> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  String _name = '';

  String _add = '';

  String _phoneNo= '';

  String _pincode ='';

  String _landmark = '';

  

   CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
   

   _save()async
  {
     if(_formKey.currentState.validate())
     {
     _formKey.currentState.save();
    await users.add({
       "name": _name,
       "contact": _phoneNo,
       "Address": _add,
       "pincode":_pincode,
       "landmark":_landmark,
      //  "orders":order

     });
    // Navigator.pushNamed(context,"/OrderSumm");

     Navigator.push(context, 
       
       MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => OrderSumm(
           name: _name,
           mobile : _phoneNo,
           address  : _add,
           pincode: _pincode,
           landmark : _landmark
               )) );

    }

    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('credentials'),
      ),

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
            child: Column(
      children: [
        Text("enter credentials carefully",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),

       Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child:IndexedStack(
              children:[ Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                     child: TextFormField(
                       validator: (input){
                       
                          if(input.isEmpty)
                          {return 'Enter Email';}
                        return null;},
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Email',
                          prefixIcon:Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1_outlined)),                            
                          onSaved: (input) => _name = input                         
                     ),
                   ),
                    Container(
                     child: TextFormField(
                       validator: (input){                           
                      if (input.isEmpty)
                   {return 'Enter Mobile';}
                   else if (input.length < 10 || input.length >10)
                   {return "Enter 10 digit mobile number";}
                          return null;},
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'contact',
                          prefixIcon:Icon(Icons.phone_android_outlined)),                            
                          onSaved: (input) => _phoneNo = input                         
                     ),
                   ),
                    Container(
                     child: TextFormField(
                       validator: (input){
                       
                          if(input.isEmpty)
                          {return 'Enter Address';}
                        return null;},
                        maxLines: null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Address',
                          prefixIcon:Icon(Icons.apartment_outlined)),                            
                          onSaved: (input) => _add = input                         
                     ),
                   ),
                    Container(
                     child: TextFormField(
                       validator: (input){
                       
                          if(input.isEmpty)
                          {return 'Enter Pincode';}
                        return null;},
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Pincode',
                          prefixIcon:Icon(Icons.pin_drop_outlined)),                            
                          onSaved: (input) => _pincode = input                         
                     ),
                   ),
                    Container(
                     child: TextFormField(
                      
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Landmark(optional)',
                          prefixIcon:Icon(Icons.pin_drop_outlined)),                            
                          onSaved: (input) => _landmark = input                         
                     ),
                   ),

                   RaisedButton(
                       onPressed: _save,

                       color: Colors.redAccent,
                       child: Text('continue',
                       style: TextStyle(color : Colors.white),), 
                       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),


        ***THANK YOU***
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Android issue as it can be tracked on the [Flutter Github repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27095)

It seems that using [Android 11 solved this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27095#issuecomment-722857855).

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27095